# connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:19001 when trying to do `expo publish`

Tags: react-native, expo

I get this error message when trying to run the `expo publish` command.

````
Building iOS bundle
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:19001
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.```

I tried updating expo to the latest version, didn't work.

I am using expo-cli version 3.11.9, node version 12.9.0 and npm version 6.10.2.

Any info would be appreciated, thanks in advance.
````

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs because the React Native application is not running. To avoid this kind of error, you must first start the application and at the same time open another window to run the compile command.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But after some research (https://forums.expo.io/t/error-when-trying-to-run-exp-publish/223), I found that deleting the `.expo` folder in your project fixes the problem.

Let me know if that worked for you.